# $this issue in php 7.1.9

Tags: php, php-7.1

I have a class which I am using $this with and since upgrading from 5.6 to 7.1 I cannot get to work. I'm confused as to why? Please see code sample below:

```
class user_BL extends BLL {

public function getCurrentUserFromSession($userid) {
            $userrecord = array();

            $query = new query();
            $query->addCriteria("userid", $userid , "=");

            $userrecords = $this->getDataByQueryObj($query, new user_DAL());

            if (isset($userrecords[0])){
                $userrecord = $userrecords[0];
                $lastlogindetails = $this->getLastLoginDetailsAsArray();
                $userrecord['logindatetime'] = astlogindetails['logindatetime']; 
            }

            return $userrecord;
        }
}
```

getLastLoginDetailsAsArray is a function on the BLL base class. The IDE interprets this ok and sees that its available to be used.

Anyhelp with this would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Deano

EDIT: the error I'm getting is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Forgot to add that it was a long day yesterday. :)

Comment: What's the error you're getting? You have a syntax error (possibly from editing the snippet?) `astlogindetails['logindatetime'];` is missing the first characters, `$l`

Comment: try parent::getLastLoginDetailsAsArray();

Comment: did you initialized the "__constructor()" if you didn't set this can cos the problem on $this.

Comment: Please explain how it's not working. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @ishegg - correct that error is from editing the snippet.

Comment: @user2297026 anything else you might have left out? Any static methods in either of those classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging into the error I've found the call was being made like this:

```
user_BL::getCurrentUserFromSession();
```

which seems to be the problem. Calling it like this:

```
$userbl = new user_BL();
$userbl->getCurrentUserFromSession();
```

Corrects this. 
Thanks for everyones help.